# Almacenar una cadena en JS, que se encuentra en un .txt/.html

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un .txt (puedo cambiarlo a .html si fuera necesario) que contiene una serie de números separados por comas. Lo que pretendo es poder operar con ellos (desde otro idex.html), es decir, hacer por ejemplo una tabla, o que se muestre uno en concreto, o a algunos darle formato.

He estado viendo AJAX, con XMLHttpRequest, pero no me sirve porque estoy en local y no tengo memoria para hacer servidor.

La cosa sería, supongo, tenerlo en una variable o cadena.

Hasta ahora solo lo muestro con un iframe el html.

Ejemplo del txt o html a tratar:

```
45,234,67,250,34,25,67,450
```

Comment: Hola, con que finalidad lo guardas en un .txt y porque no en una base de datos?

Comment: Son los datos que me proporcionan unos sensores de una placa conectada por cable ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de investigar mucho, por lo visto no es posible. No puedes navegar por tus archivos locales con js. Acabé apañandome para usar AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

**Pudieras probar algo así...**
Acá especifica la ruta del archivo mas el nombre y el formato almacenandolo en la variable "file".

```
file = fopen(getScriptPath("miArchivo.txt"), 0);
```

Luego con la función split() conviertelo en un array indicando en el primer parámetro el separador.

```
fileAsArray = file.split(",");
```

Básicamente tienes un CSV y el juego está en convertir un CSV a una matríz, split() puede servirte para eso.